Mapping a triangular image onto a sphere in POV-ray?
I have an image of a triangular texture representing the unfolded net of a regular tetrahedron. I can map this onto a tetrahedral mesh with uv-mapping to select each triangular face and ignore the bits of the rectangular image that fall outside of the actual texture. However, I would like to also be able to map the same tetrahedral texture onto a sphere. Is there any way to do that?
